# Tab to next tabindex field on down arrow key

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webform and want the users to be able to go to the next tabindex field when the down arrow is pressed (behave like the tab key). The following code works when enter key is pressed but if I change the keycode to 40 this code will not work for the down arrow key.

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
<div>
    <input name="line[]" class=""  type="text" tabindex="1"/>
</div>
<div>
    <input name="line[]" class=""  type="text" tabindex="2"/>
</div>
<div>
    <input name="line[]" class=""  type="text" tabindex="3"/>
</div>

//tab to next tabindex on enter key
<script>
    var id;
    $(document).ready(function(eOuter) {
        $('input').bind('keypress', function(eInner) {
            if (eInner.keyCode == 13){ //enter key
                var tabindex = $(this).attr('tabindex');
                tabindex++; //increment tabindex
                $('[tabindex=' + tabindex + ']').focus();

                $('#Msg').text($(this).attr('id') + " tabindex: " + tabindex + " next element: " + $('*').attr('tabindex').id);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Do not use tabindex values of 1 or greater to change the default keyboard navigation order. as per https://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/#problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arrow keys don't fire consistently on the `keypress` event, you want to use `keydown` instead

```
$('input').on('keydown', function(eInner) {

    if (eInner.which === 40) { //arrow down
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/359t3ut6/)

Your message has some issues as well, the elements don't have ID's, jQuery's `attr` returns a primitive that has no `id` property etc.

Answer (score 3):

**100%** working for `up arrow` and `down arrow`

```
$(document).ready(function(eOuter) {
     $('input').on('keydown', function(eInner) {
         var keyValue = eInner.which; //enter key
         if (keyValue == 40 || keyValue == 38){ 
             var tabindex = $(this).attr('tabindex');
             if(keyValue == 40){ //down arrow 40
                 tabindex++;
             }else{ //up arrow 38
                 tabindex--;
             }
             $('[tabindex=' + tabindex + ']').focus();
         }
     });
});
```

Comment: This is not how tabindex works, in fact it's recommended to only use tabindex=0 or tabindex=-1. See the MDN tabindex page for the full details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who wonders how this work in React/Typescript codes, here is a code snippet that works for me (to allow using ArrowDown and ArrowUp keys to achieve the effect of tab through a ul list):

```
<ul>
            {props.suggestions.map((o, i, a) => (
                <li
                    key={o.id}
                    tabIndex={props.tabIndex}
                    onClick={(e) => (props.onSelect ? props.onSelect(o) : undefined)}
                    onBlur={props.onBlur}
                    onKeyDown={(e) => {
                        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
                            if (props.onSelect) props.onSelect(o);
                        }

                        if (e.key === 'ArrowDown') {
                            e.currentTarget.nextSibling && e.currentTarget.nextSibling.focus();
                        }
                        if (e.key === 'ArrowUp') {
                            e.currentTarget.previousSibling && e.currentTarget.previousSibling.focus();
                        }
                    }}
                />
                
            ))}
        </ul>
```

The key is **e.currentTarget.nextSibling.focus()** and **e.currentTarget.previousSibling.focus()**

Comment: Just found that that currentTarget.nextSibling.focus() works in Storybook but not in fully compiled codes. Got TypeScript error in ....
Property 'focus' does not exist on type 'ChildNode'.  TS2339

Comment: For Typescript to work, needed to cast the silblings to strong type:  (e.currentTarget.nextSibling as HTMLLIElement).focus();

Comment: In my case my elements with tabIndex were not direct siblings, so I had to do this:
```if (e.key === "ArrowDown") {
  const tabs = window.document.querySelectorAll("[tabIndex]");
  const index = Array.from(tabs).indexOf(e.target as Element);
  (tabs[index + 1] as HTMLElement)?.focus();
  }```

Answer (score 0):

This was harder than I thought, but if it's important to you, as it is to us, here's what you need to do...

- walk the dom to create and maintain your own ordered list of elements that can receive focus.
- create a variable, `active`, that will track the currently focussed input.
- listen for focus events so you can update the value of `active` if the user focusses an input by tabbing or clicking.
- listen for the arrow keys, and use `active` to determine the next or previous element in your list and call `focus()` on it.
- blur. Tabbing resets to zero if the user clicks outside an input. If you want this for arrow keys, you'll have to add it. (The code below doesn't manage this)

The code below does all this (except the last point) in react. It should be easily adaptable to any other setting. It builds its list once, 500ms after it's called. This is adequate for us for the moment, but  if you're adding and removing inputs from your DOM, you'll need to manage this yourself.

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { IHasHistory, withHistory } from "./traceableEvents";


function addArrowNavigation() {

    function onFocus(e: FocusEvent & IHasHistory) {
        if (!e.history.includes("focusManager.OnFocus")) {
            const activeIndex = inputsRef.current.findIndex((anInput) => anInput === e.target);
            setActive(activeIndex);
            console.log(activeIndex + " active");
            e.history.push("focusManager.OnFocus");
        }
    }

    // stores list of all elements in the page that
    // can receive focus, in order of their appearance.
    const [inputs, setInputs] = useState([]);
    const inputsRef = useRef(inputs)
    useEffect(() => { inputsRef.current = inputs })

    // stores the currently focussed input
    const [active, setActive] = useState<number | undefined>(undefined);
    const activeRef = useRef(active)
    useEffect(() => { activeRef.current = active })

    function registerTabbable(doc: Document) {
        const inputs = [];
        function traverse(el: HTMLElement) {
            if (el.tabIndex >= 0) {
                inputs.push(el);
            }
            if (el.childNodes) {
                for (const node of el.childNodes)
                    if (node instanceof HTMLElement)
                        traverse(node);
            }
        }
        for (const node of doc.childNodes)
            if (node instanceof HTMLElement)
                traverse(node);

        console.log(inputs);
        setInputs(inputs);
    }


    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener("keydown", keyPress);
        document.addEventListener("focusin", (e) =>
            onFocus(withHistory(e))
        );

        setTimeout(() => {
            registerTabbable(document);
        }, 500);

        // Don't forget to clean up
        return function cleanup() {
            document.removeEventListener("keydown", keyPress);
        };
    }, []);

    const keyPress = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
        console.log(e.keyCode);
        if ([38, 40].includes(e.keyCode)) e.preventDefault();
        switch (e.keyCode) {
            // DOWN ARROW
            case 40: {
                const goTo = activeRef.current === undefined ? 0 : (activeRef.current + 1) % inputsRef.current.length
                inputsRef.current[goTo].focus();
                break;
            }
            // UP ARROW
            case 38: {
                const goTo = activeRef.current === undefined ? 0 : (activeRef.current - 1) % inputsRef.current.length
                inputsRef.current[goTo].focus();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The traceableEvents component, referenced above, is as follows...

```
export interface IHasHistory {
    history: string[];
}

export function withHistory<TargetShape>(target: any): TargetShape & IHasHistory {
    if (!target.history) {
        (target as IHasHistory).history = [];
    }
    return target;
}
```